# Search computer for all .git-folder with uncommited changes

Tags: git, bash

I have several project-folders on my machine, all including a `.git`-directory. I assume that all programmers have been in the situation, where they've forgotten to push something to the server. So is there a way to search all subdirectories for uncommitted/unstaged changes and list them?

Here is an example of my situation:

```
MainFolder
     |
     |-Project1
     |     |-.git # containing uncommitted changes
     |     |-index.php
     |     |-page_one.php
     |
     |-Project2
     |     |-.git # This git-status is clean
     |     |-index.php
     |     |-another_page.php
     |
     |-Project3
     |     |-.git # containing unstaged changes
     |     |-index.php
     |     |-some_page.php
     |
     |-Project4
           |-.git # containing uncommited changes
           |-index.php
           |-some_page.php
```

I'd like a list, say:

```
You need to check these .git-files:
 - MainFolder/Project1/.git 
 - MainFolder/Project3/.git 
 - MainFolder/Project4/.git
```

Comment: The difficulty with your question is that I suspect what you really want to know is whether either the working directory and/or the stage has any changes.  So I think any answer would have to check both places, because this is probably what Git itself has to do when you run `git status`.

Comment: Yeah. Ideally I wanted a bash-script (or something) the went through all sub-directories and did a 'git init' if there was a git-file, - and if there was any uncommited/unstages changes, then output the name of that git-file. I was just hoping for some easier solution. I tried peeking around in the .git-folder, - but I had no idea what I was looking for.

Comment: unstaged/uncommited changes have nothing to do with forgetting to push.

Comment: To be fair, it can do, depending on whether git is simply being used for version control or actually fed into a pipe line to build an application. We've had similar issues in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `find` do what you want?

```
find MainFolder -name .git -print -execdir git status \;
```

- `-name <name>` the file-name you are searching for
- `-print` print out all hits
- `-execdir <command>` in the subdirectory where you got a hit execute command; the trailing semicolon is required, and needs to be escaped, to build the command in the find loop

More detailed information can be found in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Answer (score 1):

I have a little bash script that I use to do this.  It won't get you the tree you're after, but it will tell you the git repo and whether there are any uncommitted changes.

```
function runCmd
{
  echo `basename $dir` "repository:"
  eval $@
  echo
}

for dir in `ls -d */`
do
  pushd $dir >> /dev/null
  if [ -d ".git" ]
  then
    runCmd $@
  fi
  popd >> /dev/null
done
```

Save this in a file called allRepo.  Then you can run whatever command you want from the top level of you file tree:

```
allRepo git fetch
allRepo git status
```

This script is nice because it's not limited to only git commands.

Comment: It sounds neat. I've just tried to implement it, - but I'm getting these four lines of error: `./allRepo: line 12: pushd: [FOLDERNAME]: No such file or directory
./allRepo: line 17: popd: directory stack empty
./allRepo: line 12: pushd: [FOLDERNAME2]: No such file or directory
./allRepo: line 17: popd: directory stack empty`
Do you know why it's giving that error? Do I need to run `git fetch` before I can run `git status` (I hope not, since that pretty much defeats the purpose of the script).

Comment: Honestly, I'm not a bash expert and in my experience you just have to fiddle with it until returns happily.  In this instance, it seems like the 'ls -d *' command isn't returning the correct folder structure.  There seem to be other good answers to this question, but if you still want to mess with this, I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `locate` (or its variants `mlocate` or `slocate`) and have `locate.db` regularly updated? I use the following script:

```
locate -b \*.git | sed 's!/\.git$!!'| while read d; do
    test -d "$d"/.git || continue
    cd "$d" && test -n "`git status --short`" && echo "$d"
done
```

PS. `locate` can return both bare (`xxx.git`) and non-bare (`xxx/.git`) directories, so I strip `/.git` and test only non-bare repos.

Comment: I didn't try this, since I found my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /Mainfolder -name ".git" -type d | awk -F\/ '{ printf "cd ";for ( i=2;i<=NF-1;i++ ) { printf "%s/",$i } printf "; git status | grep -q \"new file\" && echo \"$(pwd) Needs checking\""}' | sh
```

Utilising find with awk on one line, you find all directory that are controlled by git, then build the directory name using awk. This is then printed and git-status is executed with the result grepped for "new file". This constructed command is then piped through sh to execute it.

The text "new file" will need to be changed accordingly.

Output:

```
/Mainfolder/Project1 Needs checking
```

Comment: I didn't try this, since I found my answer above.